# Add_rewrite_rule doesn't seem to work?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to get my two custom post types to work properly. Let's say the two Custom Post Types (CPT) are books and reviews.

now i like

```
mydomain.com/books/the-great-gatsby/reviews/33
```

to show all the reviews for book the great gatsby.

In general `mydomain.com/books/{title-book}/reviews/{book_id}`

I have made bought CPT's and i have a two page templates (page-books.php and page-reviews.php). Page-books.php works as expected for page-reviews.php i am testing with a hardcoded $book_id and this works. But i need to make page-reviews.php dynamic. 
In my local setup page-reviews.php has a page_id=227. I am putting

```
echo 'Book id '.$_REQUEST['book_id'];
```

in page-reviews.php for testing purpose

so i tried

```
add_rewrite_rule('^books/([^/]*)/reviews/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=227&book_id=$matches[2]','top');
```

but i get a 404 page.

Any tips?

Comment: ok resaving the permalinks and i got redirected, but the book_id isn't parsed even with a static value `&book_id=123` parsing $_GET['book_id'] is empty.

Answer (score 0):

ok this i didn't know i had to "register" variable to use

```
function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp,$wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var('book_id');
    add_rewrite_rule('^books/([^/]*)/reviews/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=227&bookid_id=$matches[2]', 'top');
    // Once you get working, remove this next line
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);  

}
add_action('init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules');
```

and in page-reviews.php i am using

```
$book_id = $GLOBALS['wp']->query_vars['book_id'];
```

One last question: how do i fix my breadcrumbs as the books/.../reviews is not displayed in the breadcrumbs?

Comment: Thanks—where did you learn that you needed to use `add_query_var`? It's not mentioned in https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule, at least not what I've seen

Comment: it's terrible for performance to flush rewrite rules on the `init` hook, and that's not how you add new query variables, there's a dedicated hook and function for it. Likewise `get_query_var` should be used