# add_rewrite_rule doesn't work when trying to add a new parameter at the end of URL

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I wish to add a `userq` parameter at the end of a URL with the username such as `john`. I wish to change,

```
example.com/user/john
```

to,

```
example.com/user/index.php?userq=john
```

I tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161234/add-rewrite-rule-doesnt-seem-to-work) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231389/217284) and they don't work.

```
add_action('init', 'user_profile_rewrite');
function user_profile_rewrite() {
        global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
        $wp->add_query_var('userq');
        $rule = '^user/([^/]*)/?';
        $rewrite = 'user/index.php?userq=$matches[1]';
        add_rewrite_rule( $rule, $rewrite, 'top' );
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

I think the error has something to do with `user/index.php?` so I tried removing the word `user` by changing to `index.php?...` but the URL remains like the original. How to solve this?

Comment: can you be more specific? You mentioned they didn't work but didn't go into detail. Also that's not how you add a new query variable to the list, there's a dedicated filter for it, and the `add_query_var` function. It's also very bad practice to flush rewrite rules on the `init` hook. Have you used one of the rewrite rule inspector plugins? The examples in the official documentation should work better than the answers you linked to

Comment: @TomJNowell I mean when I go to 'example.com/user/john' I still get 'example.com/user/john' URL in return, not 'example.com/user/index.php?userq=john' and I also tried the 'add_query_var ' and I still don't get my URL to be rewritten.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks to you, I just installed the plugin and it says there's a rule 'user/([^/]+)/?$' and rewritten to be 'index.php?page_id=12140&um_user=$matches[1]' so I wonder if the reason I can't get it to work is that the URL has already been rewritten.

Comment: are you expecting the URL in the address bar to change? Rewrite rules are not redirects, they always map a pretty URL in to the form `index.php?quervar=value&etc...`, they can't map to arbitrary files, and they can't be used to create redirects to other URLs. Rewrite rules also have a priority/order, but I can guarantee the way that you did it in your questions code, and the way the question/answers you linked to do it, are incorrect. A briefest of looks at the official documentation for `add_rewrite_rules` shows a far superior example that is safer, more reliable, and honestly easier to write

Comment: also note that rewrite rules won't change the permalinks of posts and terms, the system for figuring out the URL of a post, and the system for figuring out the post from a URL are independent of eachother. As is canonical redirects